# Ubuntu 14.04 can't or won't connect to wifi, even after clean install

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet, suspend

I'm new to Ubuntu. I've seen there are a lot of wifi topics/questions on here already but I haven't been able to solve my problem.

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop to try it out and hopefully learn more about it. It was working great at first, connected to the wifi easily, browsed the web with no problems etc. But when I went to wake the computer up it wouldn't connect. I restarted and it connected straight away, but the next time it did it again and the restart didn't cure it.

It always shows the networks, it just won't connect to them.

Not really knowing what I was doing, I hit google and tried as many solutions as I could find, none of them worked. I tried re-installing, still no connection.

I know it's not a problem with the hardware as I've got a Windows boot that connects just fine, and when I run Ubuntu off USB before installing it I can connect no problem.

I've tried:

```
sudo service network-manager restart

sudo service dbus restart

sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"
```

and a load of other solutions that I found on here and other forums, some of them probably not that relevant to my problem. Hence the reinstall in case I'd done any damage.

```
nmcli nm returns:

Running, state, wifi-hw, wifi, wwan-hw, wwan
running, disconnected, enabled, enabled, enabled, disabled.
```

I'm not entirely sure where I should be looking to diagnose the issue or what information would be useful to people on here, let me know what would help.

Are there any common problems with wifi in Ubuntu? Have I missed something stupidly obvious? It's not really possible for me to use a wired connection atm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update/Edit-------**

I ran this:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

This is the result:

**http://paste.ubuntu.com/24717805/**

Comment: My bet it's Windows!

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: Sorry for the delay, work/different time-zones/whatever. I've run that script and posted it on Ubuntu Pastebin. Hopefully this link works: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24717805/

Comment: I posted an answer, it should get it going but we can always do more if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to reset resolv.conf and add a driver parameter, please do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

and then answer 'Yes' to the "Prepare /etc/resolv.conf for dynamic updates?" question and 'No' to the one about temporarily appending your existing config to the dynamic one, it is possible the second question will not be present. 
Reboot

Go into network manager and change the network settings to match the screenshots, to include setting IPV6 to ignore, save then reboot.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've followed those steps but I'm still not getting a connection. After start up the wifi icon does the animation as if it's trying to connect but then fails, just like before.

Comment: Please run the wireless script again so we can see if the changes stuck.

Comment: Here's the new file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24718343/

Comment: @Rob I added to my answer.

Comment: That seems to have done it! I've tried putting it to sleep and then waking it again, it takes it a while for the connection to work but it gets there eventually. Massive thanks, I was totally lost without your help. If it's of any interest here's the result of the wireless script with it working: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24718952/